# Add color to label on list in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, list, apache-flex, components

I am confused on how to get this.. so i have a user list when someone joins it adds them to a List (their username) i have a way to find out if they are admin or not i just need to know how i can change the color of each user in that list... this is an example....

If list supported html this would work fine

```
onlineUsers.addItem({label:"<font color='$ffffff'>users[i].userName+"_GUEST</font>",id:users[i].userID,guest:"True"});
userList.dataProvider = onlineUsers
```

But list do not support html, anyone know a work around with this?

Answer (score 0):

Generically, your answer is to use an itemRenderer.

All a list class does is display other components (renderers) and send those components data from the dataProvider to display.  Really, you mean the default itemRenderer doesn't support HTML.  Technically you could make an itemRenderer that would support HTML to give you the color change you need; but I'd take a different.

Add a property to the user object that specifeis whether they are an admin user or not.  Then iF the user is an admin user; then; change the color.  Conceptually like this:

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    autoDrawBackground="false" dataChange="onDataChange()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function onDataChange():void{
               labelDisplay.text = data.userName + "_Guest";
               if(data.isAdmin){
                 labelDisplay.setStyle('color',0xff0000);
               } else {
                 labelDisplay.setStyle('color',0x00FF00);
               }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" 
        /> 
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Comment: theres a problem that will change everyones color to that color :[

Comment: Are you saying you tried it and there is a bug in my code?  Or are you saying something else?  The code, as wirtten, will not change everyone's color.  If the "user" object has an isAdmin property defined; then it will be set to one color. IF the user doesn't it will be set to a different color.  That code is in the onDataChange function.  Alternatively, you could give every user an isAdmin property and set it to true for users who are Admins and false for users who are not.  Granted, I did write the code in a browser; so there may be bugs.

Comment: it does have a admin property but when i do the     .setStyle('color',0xff0000);

Comment: it sets all name as that color

Comment: You have to add one an isAdmin property to your objects for the code to select a color other than "Default".  I'll edit my answer to make my suggestion more clear.